# What is the so-called held out training set?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I heard about the "hold out evaluation set" from [C3W1L05](https://youtu.be/M3qpIzy4MQk) and the "held-out test set" from the [deep learning book on page 119 of chapter 5](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html#page=119).

I thought "held out" or "hold out" implies not being trained, but in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf#page=9) I see "held-out training data". What does that mean? Do the three just a standard saying of "evaluation set", "test set" and "training set"? Maybe it is the so-called training-dev set?

Comment: I can understand your confusion because on its face the phrase seems to be a contradiction in terms. My speculation is that the authors partitioned the training set to create a holdout set, but the context doesn't make clear that this interpretation is correct. I think the only way to know for certain is to contact the authors.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica OK. I will contact them with the link to this question.